# xhr GET request returning 406 only when in iframe

Tags: javascript, php, html, xmlhttprequest

My xhr requested resource returns code 406 ONLY when in an iframe

Here is the xhr code that is in the script that the is inside the iframe:

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp12' . $orderID . '=new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {  // code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp12' . $orderID . '=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp12' . $orderID . '.onreadystatechange=function() {
if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200) {
  //Execute code here...
}
}
xmlhttp12' . $orderID . '.open("GET","../../scheduling/php/cron.php?error=true&name=' . $cname . '&id=' . $orderID . '&address=' . mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,str_replace("#","",$address)) . '&city=' . mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$city) . '&state=' . $state . '&zip=' . $zip . '",true);
xmlhttp12' . $orderID . '.send();
```

Here are the Request Headers shown in the console:

```
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,da;q=0.8,pt;q=0.7,fr;q=0.6,la;q=0.5
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: PHPSESSID=f15733e5f59c258ae3a2d50640531810
Host: marketforceapp.com
Pragma: no-cache
Referer: http://marketforceapp.com/marketforce/scheduling/php/sync- 
orders.php?dbName=mburton9_mf_allsteelcarports&xx=%3C? php%20echo%20rand();%20?%3E&fn=Mike%20Burton&edit_route=&schedule_state=
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_2) 
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36
```

Here are the Response Headers shown in the console:

```
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 226
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Date: Fri, 08 Feb 2019 16:42:05 GMT
Server: nginx/1.14.1
```

It seems that the Origin Header needs to be set in order for this work, but it does not seem to be setting automatically.

If I try and set it manually, I get an error:
`Refused to set unsafe header`

I need to figure out how to allow this resource within the iframe. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, this iframe is on the site on a different host, try set in your cron.php header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`

Comment: Actually, this is across the same host - same domain.